# Vertical alignment not working

Tags: html, css, chess

I'm making a chess board and I need to center the numbers for the rows vertically. I found the CSS attribute `vertical-align` but for some reason my text isn't being centered it seems. All of the numbers are in their own table cell.

[image: Chess Board]

My CSS code looks as follows:

```
.Numbers{
    background-color: #700000;
    width: 20px;
    font-family: verdana;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: #700000;
}
```

And here is some of the html:

```
<tr><td class = "Numbers"></td>
```

I'd greatly appreciate any insight, thanks!

Comment: You need to post your HTML...

Comment: Ok, I did it! thanks for letting me know

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` is applied relative to the next higher (outer) level; check what is the next outer level; maybe that box is just one text-line high, so it is 'middle' relative to that.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the higher level of `<td>`. 
And add `!important` in your css if you wanna make this rule more important. Preview:https://jsfiddle.net/k3nndmnt/2/

Comment: I have attributes for every td like this: `td {
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 padding:0px;
 display:inline-block;
 border:1px solid black;
}` so maybe thats affecting it?

Comment: You can try remove display:inline-block; Preview:https://jsfiddle.net/k3nndmnt/4/

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only work for horizontal centering. Try to either make equal top and bottom paddings or use line height:

```
.Numbers { padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 30px; }
```

or,

```
.Numbers { height: 100px; line-height: 100px; white-space: nowrap; }
```

Answer (score 0):

use below css property in your parent td class.

`vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: Didn't work, I think it has something to do with my display for them being inline-block